# Customizing certain part labels in exam package

Tags: exam

I am using the package `exam`, which is absolutely great!

But I have one desire left:
I want to have kind of "bonus parts", that are labeled different than the others:

[image: Example for parts]

In this case, e.g.

```
(a) First
(b) Second
(*) Bonus part
```

I see two different approaches to do so:

- In the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) is a description of `\partlabel`. But it changes all part labels, not certain ones.
- The second approach would be to use subparts (which I don't need in another way) and overwrite the `\subpartlabel`. But then all `\subpart`s are intended more then the `\part`s.

Here is my MWE from above.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}

\question
First Question

\begin{parts}

\part
First

\part
Second

\part
Bonus part
    
\end{parts}
    
\end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\partlabel` to `(*)` immediately before the bonus part.

```
\renewcommand\partlabel{(*)}
\part
Bonus part
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}

\question
First Question

\begin{parts}

\part
First

\part
Second

\renewcommand\partlabel{(*)}
\part
Bonus part

\end{parts}
    
\end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was easy.. :D Thank you!

Comment: Note that the old \partlabel is restored by \end{parts}.